# word synonym / antonym detection

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, data-science, bert-language-model

I need to create a classifier that takes 2 words and determines if they are synonyms or antonyms. I tried nltk's antsyn-net but it doesn't have enough data.

example:

- capitalism <-[antonym]-> socialism
- capitalism =[synonym]= free market
- god <-[antonym]-> atheism
- political correctness <-[antonym]-> free speach
- advertising =[synonym]= marketing

I was thinking about taking a BERT model, because may be some of the relations would be embedded  in it and transfer-learn on a data-set that I found.

Comment: Any embedding with a logistic regression on top or simple cosine similarity with a threshold may do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a following pipeline:

1. Construct a training set from existing dataset of synonyms and antonyms (taken e.g. from the Wordnet thesaurus). You'll need to craft negative examples carefully.
2. Take a pretrained model such as BERT and fine-tune it on your tasks. If you choose BERT, it should be probably `BertForNextSentencePrediction` where you use your words/prhases instead of sentences, and predict 1 if they are synonyms and 0 if they are not; same for antonyms.

Comment: isn't all Bert models trained on on next sentence prediction?

Comment: Yes, all BERT models are trained for the NSP problem. `BertForNextSentencePrediction` is just a convenient code wrapper from the library https://huggingface.co/transformers/

Comment: @DavidDale, did you try your approach and found it effective? Because I could see that BERT knows nothing about semantical contrasts - see my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64738455/google-bert-and-antonym-detection. Would fine-tuning it on synonym/antonym data set improve the situation?

Comment: I haven't tied the fine-tuning approach, so I'm not 100% sure. 
My guess is that BERT does know something about antonyms, but this is buried in a lot of another knowledge - that's why BERT sentence embeddings of texts with opposite meanings look similar. And I hope that fine tuning is able to extract this knowledge from BERT.